# Web site redirects with incorrect URL

Tags: wordpress, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm trying to deploy a wordpress in a swarm at the following address:

http://apps.exemplo.com/ti/bc

When you access http://apps.example.com/ti/bc, wordpress redirects to
http://apps.example.com/wp-admin/install.php omitting "ti / bc".
Is it possible to correct this behavior only by using traefik, without changing code inside the wordpress image?

Look my stack:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always    
    networks:
     - default
     - proxy-apps    
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: lpddb:3333
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
    deploy:
      labels:
       - "traefik.port=80"
       - "traefik.docker.network=proxy-apps"
       - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/ti/bc"
       - "traefik.backend=wordpress"       
    volumes:
      - base-conhecimento:/var/www/html

networks:
  proxy-apps:
    external: true

volumes:
  base-conhecimento:
    driver: local
```